# Convert cipher text with symbols to string in java

Tags: java, aes, inputstream

i'm having a problem during my project at school. what im trying to do is read plain text file and encrypt it using AES 128 which will give me a cipher text file, then i want to take the cipher file and convert it string to embed it into and image.
the AES class dealing with inputstream and the steganography dealing with string. If i extract the cipher text from image and save it to file to read it again using AES i get problem because there are some symbol which make a different between the file.

AES encryption method:

```
    public static void encrypt(int keyLength, char[] password, InputStream input, OutputStream output){

    if (keyLength != 128 && keyLength != 192 && keyLength != 256) {
        throw new InvalidKeyLengthException(keyLength);
    }


    byte[] salt = generateSalt(SALT_LENGTH);
    Keys keys = keygen(keyLength, password, salt);


    Cipher encrypt = null;
    try {
        encrypt = Cipher.getInstance(CIPHER_SPEC);
        encrypt.init(Cipher.ENCRYPT_MODE, keys.encryption);
    } catch (NoSuchAlgorithmException | NoSuchPaddingException impossible) {
    } catch (InvalidKeyException e) { 
        throw new StrongEncryptionNotAvailableException(keyLength);
    }


    byte[] iv = null;
    try {
        iv = encrypt.getParameters().getParameterSpec(IvParameterSpec.class).getIV();
    } catch (InvalidParameterSpecException impossible) {
    }


    output.write(keyLength / 8);
    output.write(salt);
    output.write(keys.authentication.getEncoded());
    output.write(iv);


    byte[] buffer = new byte[BUFFER_SIZE];
    int numRead;
    byte[] encrypted = null;
    while ((numRead = input.read(buffer)) > 0) {
        encrypted = encrypt.update(buffer, 0, numRead);
        if (encrypted != null) {
            output.write(encrypted);
        }
    }
    try {
        encrypted = encrypt.doFinal();
    } catch (IllegalBlockSizeException | BadPaddingException impossible) {
    }
    if (encrypted != null) {
        output.write(encrypted);
    }
}
```

Steganography encode method:

```
public boolean encode(BufferedImage img, String message) {

    BufferedImage image = user_space(img);
    image = add_text(image, message);

    return (setImage(image));
}
```

If i can make steganography to return text file i think that would solve the problem.

what do you think?

Comment: You're looking for Base64.

Comment: Encrypt/Decrypt part is working fine. I can encrypt and decrypt a file and i can embed a text and extract. but to embed a cipher text that the problem. how can i change the embed method to take inpu tstream and extract output stream?

Comment: Well, how do you embed the text? Do you convert each string to an ascii code and hide its bits in the pixels? A stream of encrypted bytes is nothing more than 1s and 0s, where each byte has 8 bits.

Comment: Could you please check these two files: https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/17010976/Steganography.java  https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/17010976/AES.java

Comment: Edit your question to add any code relevant to it. Links to your code are less inconvenient and may become obsolete. Also, read [mcve](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: Sorry for that, but my dead line is tomorrow morning. i think i find the problem, there is i little different between the output cipher text from AES and the cipher text after been extracted from the image. here is an example: "¦ÌÕqÿ|ÄÚƒÆBSvøzÞsâXºë¢O]" and "¦ÌÕqÿ|ÄÚƒÆB?SvøzÞsâXºë¢O]" they both ANSI but i don't know what is the problem. any suggestion?